# How to Web Deploy ASP.NET 5 to AWS IIS using VS2015?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, webdeploy

The Publish Web wizard in Visual Studio 2015 no longer allows you to create a new profile and specify the connection parameters. [You can see what it looks like in the official docs here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis-with-msdeploy.html#publishing-with-visual-studio-2015).

As such there appears to be no way to use the Web Deploy to publish to AWS other than publishing to the file system and manually copying that across yourself.

How can I publish a ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 website directly to an EC2 AWS instace using Web Deploy now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to import the publish profile until they make improvements in the next preview version:

> We are working on simplifying the experience for the next version.

I haven't tried but I assume you could create the profile file yourself using the specification:

[Generate a Profile XML File](http://www.iis.net/learn/web-hosting/joining-the-web-hosting-gallery/generate-a-profile-xml-file)

Comment: That works, thanks a lot, FYI after importing the handcrafted .publishsettings you are taken to the same old Connection page where to you can edit the settings in the wizard.